# How can I add code that will call the javascript within a block every minute?

Tags: ajax

I have a block that contains javascript which calls a website that sends an ad to this block (see below: Note: I changed the domain name to adserveringwebsite).
How can I add code that will call the below javascript every minute so that a different ad will show up every minute instead of just one ad at page load?

```
<script src="http://www.adserveringwebsite.net/1e-kn99655"></script>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be Drupal related in any way? If you are wondering about Javascript in general, I think the question belongs on stackoverflow, and if you are wondering about the proper way to add the relevant Javascript to your site, then the question should be significantly rephrased. I fixed your <script> tags.

Comment: Drupal 7 has an AJAX API that is not available from plain PHP/JavaScript. The OP is then asking about a block, which is a concept very specific to Drupal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To throw in some old-skool, and realize it's up to you to drupalize all of this if your ad site url is dynamic, but, you could also throw all of this in a separate static file and call it from an iframe inside your block and use refresh, eg, in the file, let's say it's /minute_by_minute_ad.htm:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="http://www.adserveringwebsite.net/1e-kn99655"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then your block would contain something along the lines of:

```
<iframe src="/minute_by_minute_ad.htm"></iframe>
```

which would have a potentially added benefit of some speed improvements with ad loads in the iframe (debated heavily online but I've seen some).

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use JavaScript's [setTimeout() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout):

To elaborate, place the code that calls your ad server inside a JS function.

Then, use `setTimeout()`, as demonstrated in the website I linked to, to call it at every x interval.

Answer (score 1):

I think the [Block Refresh](http://drupal.org/project/block_refresh) module will do what you want out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Using an iframe isn't "the drupal way".

The drupal way is using AJAX to reload only the block. This is the same thing that [Block Refresh](http://drupal.org/project/block_refresh) does.

BUT... if you don't want the overhead of *another* module and you want to do it in your own module (I'm assuming your module is called 'mymodule' and the delta of the block is 'mymodule-delta'):

Make sure you include a javascript code, use this in your block content generation function:

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/mymodule.js', array('every_page'=>FALSE));
```

The javascript file should have something like this in it:

```
(function ($) {
    setInterval(function() {
        $('#block-mymodule-myblock-delta .content').load('/myblock', function (response,status,xhr){
            if (status == 'error'){// some error checking
                $('#block-mymodule-myblock-delta .content').html("connection lost");
            }    
        });
    }, 60 * 1000); // running every 60 seconds
})(jQuery);
```

That's going to fire an AJAX call to '/myblock' and fill the '#block-mymodule-myblock-delta' element with the content.

Now back in your module, you'll need to make the '/myblock' page like this:

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['myblock'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'myblock_via_ajax',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}

function myblock_via_ajax(){
    $block = module_invoke('mymodule','block_view','myblock-delta');
    print $block['content'];
}
```